# AngularJS - Radio buttons in a loop?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-directive

We are using ASP.NET MVC and AngularJS (Newbie on Angular) and I'm really stuck with bloated html.

I have a bunch of radio button choices that are true/false but are bound to a nullable (bool?)

This works below just fine, but it's a lot of repeating code. Can it be shrunk using the wonders of Angular? (We're going to have a lot of these kinds of yes/no/no choice controls)

```
        <div class="rdio rdio-primary col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
            <input type="radio"
                   name="@(Html.NameFor(x => x.IsUSAResident))"
                   id="resTrue"
                   ng-value="true"
                   required
                   ng-model="model.IsUSAResident">
            <label for="resTrue" class="pull-left">Yes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="rdio rdio-primary col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
            <input type="radio"
                   name="@(Html.NameFor(x => x.IsUSAResident))"
                   id="resFalse"
                   ng-value="false"
                   required
                   ng-model="model.IsUSAResident">

            <label for="resFalse" class="pull-left">No</label>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can shrink it using `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-init="options = [{id:'resTrue',value:true,label:'Yes'},{id:'resFalse',value:false,label:'No'}]">
    <div ng-repeat="option in options"
        class="rdio rdio-primary col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
            <input type="radio"
                   name="@(Html.NameFor(x => x.IsUSAResident))"
                   id="{{option.id}}"
                   ng-value="option.value"
                   required
                   ng-model="model.IsUSAResident">
               <label for="{{option.id}}" class="pull-left">{{option.label}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are ways to improve this code further.  One would be to create a controller to hold the options (to get rid of `ng-init`):

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('yesNoRadioCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.options = [
        {id:'resTrue', value:true, label: 'Yes'},
        {id:'resFalse', value:false, label: 'No'}
    ];
});
```

The corresponding markup:

```
<div ng-controller="yesNoRadioCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="option in options"
        class="rdio rdio-primary col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
            <input type="radio"
                   name="@(Html.NameFor(x => x.IsUSAResident))"
                   id="{{option.id}}"
                   ng-value="option.value"
                   required
                   ng-model="model.IsUSAResident">
               <label for="{{option.id}}" class="pull-left">{{option.label}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

This can be made more compact and reusable with directives.  Let me know if you'd like to see that.

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan is right. You can save some space, with just `ng-repeat`'ing your radio-inputs.

Here's how you could create your own directive and implement some more radio inputs, with much smaller code:

#### [» Demo on plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/VuidWr4iwqwoh0O8nfOw/preview)

#### JS

```
angular.module('foobar', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.zuzu = "a value";
  
    $scope.bars = [
      {id:"one"},
      {id:"two"}, 
      {id:"three"}
    ];
  
    for(i=0;i<$scope.bars.length;i++) {
      $scope.bars[i]["name"] = 'just-a-radio-group';
    }
  }])
  .directive('myRadio', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        data: '=',
        ngModel: '=ngModel'
      },
      templateUrl: 'template.html'
    };
  });
```

---

#### HTML (index.html)

```
<body ng-app="foobar">  
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <h3>{{zuzu}}</h3>
    <!-- they won't update the scope -->
    <my-radio ng-repeat="bar in bars" ng-model="zuzu" data="bar"></my-radio>

    <!-- they will update the scope -->
    <my-radio ng-model="zuzu" data="bars[0]"></my-radio>
    <my-radio ng-model="zuzu" data="bars[1]"></my-radio>
    <my-radio ng-model="zuzu" data="bars[2]"></my-radio>
  </div>
</body>
```

#### HTML (template.html)

```
<div class="rdio rdio-primary col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <input type="radio"
           name="data.name"
           id="data.id"
           ng-value="data.id"
           required
           ng-model="ngModel">
         
    <label for="data.name"
           class="pull-left"
           >
               {{data.id}}
           </label>
</div>
```

*Additional note, why ng-repeating the custom-directive won't update ng-model:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1913*